# Using WP functions such as the_title() in an included php file

Tags: php, include

I'm including a php file in single.php, in the loop.

Is it possible to use WP variables such as the_title(), the_date(), etc in the included php file?

Comment: This is a simple *yes/no* question that isn't well-suited to WPSE. Could you clarify your question, to describe the problem - if any - that you are experiencing while trying to include a template part file inside of `single.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the title into a variable, and use the variable in the included PHP instead:

```
$title = get_the_title();
include "yourfile.php";
```

yourfile.php:

```
<?php
echo $title;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes the title will work for a file. You can use get_template_part() function to inlude your file within a wordpress template file like single.php

[Function Reference/get template part](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WordPress functions and template tags should work just fine in a **template-part file** included inside of a WordPress template file, such as `single.php`. To verify: copy/paste the code from the included file *directly into `single.php`*, and verify that the code works as intended.